# Devise 3.1 Upgrade Invalid Token Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise, devise-confirmable

My app has been using devise (3.1.0, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.2.4), so the current version is 3.1.0. With this upgrade there is a new way Devise does token confirmation ([blog](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/)).

When I click on the email link it leads to an invalid token error, so I'm trying to find out how to resolve this. Please let me know any pointers you have. Thank you.

Comment: Double-check that the email link is taking you to the proper environment. I had the same issue once when testing in development: the email link was taking me to the production site and giving an invalid token error.

Answer (score 2):

With 3.1.0, Devise has changed the way it handles token authentication.  Rather than storing an unencrypted token in the database, Devise now encrypts that token and sends the unencrypted token in the confirmation email.  You will need to set `config.secret_key` in order to facilitate this encryption.  More info on that here: [Devise Secret Key was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080910/devise-secret-key)

Thus, if you have an old email, or an old token in the database, it is not likely to match what you expect.  You can set

```
config.allow_insecure_token_lookup = true
```

in your Devise initializer file to remedy this problem, but this is supposed to be a short-term solution while you wait for users to click on the confirmation emails that you sent out before the switch.

Lastly, if you've changed the mail message to reference the token directly (e.g. `@user.reset_password_token`), you are using the encrypted version in the email and will need to change it to reference the `@token` variable defined by Devise instead.  Here's an example email: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/2a8d0f9beeb31cd2287094c5dcf843d0bd069eb8/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb#L5