# Actions on my production app are not working through Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

The changes I make on my app are readily seen on my localhost:3000, however, if I got to it through the link (http://amanjotkaur-bloccit.herokuapp.com/) the actions such as sign up or sign in are not working. Getting this message error: We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

I've ran heroku logs on vagrant and this is what I got:

```
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309885+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `exec_no_cache'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309886+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:187:in `columns'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309891+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `yield'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309905+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309909+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309911+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309914+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309922+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309906+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309908+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309913+00:00 app[web
.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309932+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309887+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:976:in `column_definitions'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309893+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `columns'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309907+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309912+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309918+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309925+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309927+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309936+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309955+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309894+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309931+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309938+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309957+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309962+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309898+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:23:in `new'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309901+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309902+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309903+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309923+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309954+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309919+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309933+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309958+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309965+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309920+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309928+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309937+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309960+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309968+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309998+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309963+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310001+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309973+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310000+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309969+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309993+00:00 app[web.1]:   ven
dor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310005+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309976+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309997+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310007+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309972+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309996+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309992+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309975+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309970+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.309994+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310008+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310010+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310024+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310011+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310016+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310027+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310034+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310021+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310036+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310017+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310029+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310037+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310013+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310018+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310030+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310039+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310012+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310028+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310019+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310038+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310022+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310032+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310040+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310023+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-09-10T19:01:24.310041+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I don't see any errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your gem file have the right dev and production database for Heroku? I got a similar error when I forgot to add postgres.

```
 group :production do
      gem 'pg'
      gem 'rails_12factor'
    end

    group :development do
      gem 'sqlite3'
    end
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Devise error (based on both what causes it -- Sign Up and Sign In, but not About -- and on the "Warden" in your error logs).

It's possible Devise has simply not been configured correctly.

Take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139172/app-using-devise-gem-giving-application-error-on-heroku).

In your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file, you need to set something as a secret key. Generate one using `rake secret` (in the CL) if you haven't yet. And then save it as an environment variable and make sure that's on Heroku and your local environment.

If you already have a secure, environment-variabled key, it's probably another Devise config issue.