# Rails: How to set secret key for Devise in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, configuration, secret-key

I added the Devise gem then followed the instructions and ran `rails generate devise:install`, the result was the following:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:487:in        `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)

config.secret_key = 'abc123'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
```

How do I 'restart' my application? And how and where do I set the secret key?

Comment: Why is this question getting negative votes?  Is something wrong with it?

Comment: I am also surprised.

Answer (score 22):

In order to generate a secret run:

```
bundle exec rake secret
```

and copy the result from the console to the devise initializer (`config/initializers/devise.rb`)

```
config.secret_key = '4fce3c1c860216b8......'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line to your `config/initializers/devise.rb` to set the secret key (replace the example value below with a more secure and random key):

```
 config.secret_key = 'yoursecretkey'
```

After that just stop your Rails server and start it again. Also see this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080910/devise-secret-key).