# Nokogiri won't let me bundle install in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I've seen this question asked and tried everything I've seen suggested.

I got a new macbook and am looking to set up an existing app. When i clone the app, it will not bundle install and acts like Rails is not installed, even though it works in other directories.

I tried removing version numbers from gemfile and deleting gemfile.lock. I tried bundle update. I'm on osx 10.9.4, rails 4.1.5 and ruby 2.1.1.

the error I am getting:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.3.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have rvm installed. I tried reinstalling homebrew, rails and ruby.

What could it be?

Comment: Have you tried `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1`? Without seeing more of the error message, it is impossible to tell you why it failed to install.

Comment: yup, I don't get an error. I only get an error when I run 'bundle install'

Comment: does a `gem list` show it as installed?

Comment: thanks for your help! finally stumbled onto the right thing, posted below -

Answer (score 35):

Ok, phew. This worked:

http://jasdeep.ca/2013/10/installing-nokogiri-fails-os-x-mavericks/

```
xcode-select --install
gem install nokogiri
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

then, the pg gem wouldnt let bundle install. this fixed it - [Installing PG gem on OS X - failure to build native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-failure-to-build-native-extension)

```
brew update
brew install postgresql
gem install pg
```

then... bundle install worked, finally, but rails s was giving me an error, which this fixed: [Devise Secret Key was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080910/devise-secret-key)

just had to add the line w/the secret key to the config/initializers/devise.rb right before the last 'end'

hope this helps anyone who upgrades to Mavericks / gets a new computer that comes with it installed!

Comment: amazing. i never ever would have figured those steps out. free help like this on the internet makes the world a better place. you are a good netizen

Answer (score 0):

First try to do this `sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev`, then try to install